# Zabbix triggers - if power of fiber optical line (in dB) is continuously weakening

Tags: networking, triggers, monitoring, zabbix

I have an interesting task to monitor network traffic.
I am monitoring lot of interfaces, mainly RX uplinks in our network. And I have normal graphs.
As you can see sometimes on some uplink I see traffic or power of fiber optical line continuously weakening.

I need to define triggers:
1 dB decreasing in 1 hour (if dB value will decrease minus 1 dB in last 1 hour, for example i have -30 dB and in 1 hour will decrease to -31 dB)
1,5 dB decreasing in 1 day
2 dB decreasing in 1 month
2,5 dB decreasing in 6 months
3 dB / 1 year

The goal is to get information "on time" about continuously weakening uplink, because we need to manage on time the repair of the cable.

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

See the "time shift" functionality in [trigger functions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) - you can compare the last value with the value some time (one hour) ago.

More advanced alerting could be implemented with [predictive trigger functions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/triggers/prediction), although that does not seem to be necessary for your current needs.